# Alter a live table to make a key non-unique

Tags: mysql, unique, alter-table

I saw some other questions related to this, but they were not MySQL.

The database is a live database, so I don't want to delete and recreate the table. I simply want to make a column no longer unique, which is less permissive in nature so it shouldn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If your column was defined unique using `UNIQUE` clause, then use:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP INDEX constraint_name
```

, or, if your constraint was implicitly named,

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP INDEX column_name
```

If it was defined unique using `PRIMARY KEY` clause, use:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

Note, however, that if your table is `InnoDB`, dropping `PRIMARY KEY` will result in implicit recreation of your table and rebuilding all indexes, which will lock the table and may make it inaccessible for quite a long time.

Comment: I tried to drop the unique key but its giving error .
will it be possible to do so or i need to re create the table .

Comment: @Ranbir: please post it as another question

Comment: Wasn't question about how to make key non-unque, not how to drop it? If the only approach is to drop the key and re-create it without `unique` constraint, it would be nice to see that mentioned in the answer...

Answer (score 6):

These are instructions for phpmyadmin app (if you are using phpMyAdmin) ::

In a some cases, the developer (you) may not want to drop it but rather just modify the "uniqueness" to "not-unique".

Steps :

1. Go to the table in context, where you want to make the modification
2. Click on the "Structure" tab (mostly next to Browse)
3. Look for the "+Indexes" link, just under the columns. Yeah... now click it
4. Now you can see all the "Indexes" and you can now click on the "DROP" button or link to modify.

Answer was found here :
Source : https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/164827-phpmyadmin-how-to-make-not-unique/

Answer (score 4):

Although the accepted answer is incorrect (see comments), the suggested workaround is possible. But it is not correct too, at least for a "live table", as asked.

To lower the impact you should create a new index at first, and then delete the old one:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX idx_new (column);
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP INDEX idx_old;
```

This avoids using the table (column) without index at all, which can be quite painful for clients and the MySQL itself.

Answer (score 3):

Just `DROP` the unique index. There *shouldn't* be a problem with the fact that it is a live DB. If it is a really large table, you may block some queries temporarily while the index is removed. But that *should* only happen if you were adding an index.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP INDEX index_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

*MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast* [(MySQL Manual).](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

If the unique key that you want to make non-unique is used by a foreign key constraint, then you'll get an error when dropping it. You will have to recreate it on the same line:

```
alter table mytable drop KEY myUniqueKey, add key myUniqueKey (myColumn);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the constraint or the index that is associated to that column name. To remove the it, you need to drop it. Here is how you do it:

First, find the name of the unique index or unique constraint. You can use the following query to find the index name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name' AND
    TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name' AND
    COLUMN_NAME = 'the_column_that_is_unique';
```

Say for example we have the table pets in the database animals and each of them pets have a lucky number. By mistake we made the lucky_number column unique but the pets can have the same lucky number. Here is how we find the constraint associated with that column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'animals' AND
    TABLE_NAME = 'pets' AND
    COLUMN_NAME = 'lucky_number';
```

And we must get the following output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL5k3.png)

After that we need to drop it. We can do it by running the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP INDEX constraint_name;
```

In our example the above command becomes:

```
ALTER TABLE pets DROP INDEX lucky_number;
```