# How to alter table to change column from UNIQUE to NOT UNIQUE?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to alter live mysql table to make a key non unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140402/how-to-alter-live-mysql-table-to-make-a-key-non-unique)

Is there a way to change a column from UNIQUE to NOT UNIQUE?

Comment: Possibly answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140402/how-to-alter-live-mysql-table-to-make-a-key-non-unique

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Which pages of the documentation did you read on the topic of `UNIQUE` columns that did not help you, and for what reason?

Answer (score 3):

If there's a unique index defined on the column, simply `drop index index_name`