# MySQL not dropping index for unique constraint

Tags: mysql

I created a table and assigned a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` to a specific column.

```
... column_name INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNQUE
```

Now I no longer want the column to have the unique constraint, and so I tried modifying that:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP INDEX column_name
```

like I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140402/alter-a-live-table-to-make-a-key-non-unique).

The above query executes successfully the first time. But when I try inserting duplicate values in the `column_name` column, I still get the error

```
#1062 Duplicate entry '10' for key column_name_2
```

Which, I presume, means the Constraint still remains on the table. (Also funny how `_2` gets appended to the column name). But if I repeat the above `ALTER` statement, I get

```
 #1091 - Can't DROP 'column_name'; check that column/key exists
```

I also tried

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP INDEX UNIQUE
```

and it gives me the error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNIQUE' at line 1
```

Don't know if I'm missing something, but how do I remove the `UNIQUE` constraint from this column?

Comment: alter table mytable drop unique constraint uk_mytable; -- doesnt work...  https://codeghar.wordpress.com/2008/03/28/drop-unique-constraint-in-mysql/

Comment: Thanks @Paolof76, this tutorial says to use the syntax `alter table mytable drop index uk_mytable` which is what I've done (as stated in my question)

Comment: can you post SHOW CREATE TABLE  of your table?

Comment: First code block of the question shows how the column was created. It's quite a large table. Do you want me to still show everything anyway?

Comment: Thanks, @Paolof76! running SHOW CREATE TABLE actually pointed me to the source of my problem! I've posted an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came up because I had earlier ran the following query, in trying to remove the `UNIQUE` constraint.:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE column_name column_name INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

This somehow created a new column called `column_name_2` and assigned it the `UNIQUE` constraint. So when I ran `SHOW CREATE TABLE` like @Paolof76 suggested, I found among the columns:

```
UNIQUE KEY `column_name_2` (`column_name`)
```

which i presume got created due to the `ALTER` statement above.
So I ran

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP INDEX column_name_2
```

which eliminated the unique key and solved my problem.
Thanks for the heads-up @Paolof76!