# Is it possible to alter a MySQL unique index to non-unique without recreating it

Tags: mysql, database, database-migration

Is it possible to alter a MySQL unique index to non-unique without recreating it (`DROP` and `CREATE`)?

I'm using MySQL version 8.0.19.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alter a live table to make a key non-unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140402/alter-a-live-table-to-make-a-key-non-unique)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, in MySQL it is not possible to change the definition of an index without dropping it and recreating it. There is no `ALTER INDEX` statement.

Correction: You can rename an index without rebuilding it. You can make an index visible/invisible without rebuilding it.

Comment: Even for "small changes" like updating a comment?

Comment: Perhaps it would be possible to do that, but there is no supported syntax for altering the comment of an index.

Answer (score 2):

If you've meant that you want to avoid dropping the unique index, then please read Bill Karwin's answer, which properly describes that it's not possible.

However, if you've meant that you want to recreate an index without dropping and recreating the table, then it's certainly possible, like:

```
DROP INDEX indexname on tablename;
```

and then

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indexname ON tablename(columnname);
```